# Different page appearence when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I try to use some [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/) widgets, and they work fine in development. But when I deploy my app to Heroku, its appearance changes dramatically.

I wrote a sample page with a TreeView widget. This is how it renders in development:

[image: tree view in development]

And in production on Heroku:

[image: tree view in production]

As it can be seen, list markers (tree markers?) are missing.

I suspect the issue has something to do with the asset pipeline, since doing `rake assets:precompile` breaks things in development as well (and `rake assets:clean` reverts it back). But that confuses me because my [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) header works just fine in both development and production (though there are some `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/Bootstrap/loading.gif")` errors in Heroku logs).

**Gemfile**:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
gem "ancestry"
gem "bootstrap-sass"
gem "will_paginate"
gem "bootstrap-will_paginate"
gem "truncate_html"
gem "slim-rails"
gem "kendoui-rails"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem "minitest"

  platform :ruby do
    gem 'therubyracer'
  end
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
end

group :development do
  gem "nifty-generators"
  gem "annotate"
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.1.3'

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', require: 'bcrypt'
```

**development.rb**:

```
config.cache_classes = false
config.whiny_nils = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.active_support.deprecation = :log
config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = true
```

**production.rb**:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
```

Does anyone know how to fix that? Any help is appreciated.

---

**Update 1**.

Thank you all for your comments, here are the additional info.

Heroku log:

```
2013-02-23T02:37:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/environment_test/index" for 193.169.36.82 at 2013-02-23 02:37:50 +0000
2013-02-23T02:37:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by EnvironmentTestController#index as HTML
2013-02-23T02:37:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered environment_test/index.html.slim within layouts/application (23.3ms)
2013-02-23T02:37:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.slim (57.2ms)
2013-02-23T02:37:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 159ms (Views: 158.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2013-02-23T02:37:50+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/environment_test/index host=biotriz.herokuapp.com fwd="193.169.36.82" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=2ms connect=20ms service=394ms status=200 bytes=1253
2013-02-23T02:37:50+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-43a283ce09b9af356379df3e89b8b1cc.css host=biotriz.herokuapp.com fwd="193.169.36.82" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=186674
2013-02-23T02:37:51+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-8ac08b06d5d57f91da7af9d1e1c345c0.js host=biotriz.herokuapp.com fwd="193.169.36.82" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=7ms connect=20ms service=64ms status=200 bytes=648803
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=biotriz.herokuapp.com fwd="193.169.36.82" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/environment_test/index.json" for 193.169.36.82 at 2013-02-23 02:37:55 +0000
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by EnvironmentTestController#index as JSON
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/glyphicons-halflings-white-6cccd17a7aed91dbc0157d343c68c0d9.png host=biotriz.herokuapp.com fwd="193.169.36.82" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=3ms service=66ms status=200 bytes=8777
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 104ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 31.9ms)
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/Bootstrap/loading.gif" for 193.169.36.82 at 2013-02-23 02:37:55 +0000
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/Bootstrap/loading.gif"):
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/Bootstrap/loading.gif host=biotriz.herokuapp.com fwd="193.169.36.82" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=1ms connect=12ms service=56ms status=404 bytes=728
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/environment_test/index.json host=biotriz.herokuapp.com fwd="193.169.36.82" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=6ms connect=16ms service=121ms status=200 bytes=390
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/Bootstrap/sprite.png" for 193.169.36.82 at 2013-02-23 02:37:55 +0000
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/Bootstrap/sprite.png"):
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-23T02:37:55+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/Bootstrap/sprite.png host=biotriz.herokuapp.com fwd="193.169.36.82" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=728
2013-02-23T02:38:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/environment_test/index.json?id=33" for 193.169.36.82 at 2013-02-23 02:38:19 +0000
2013-02-23T02:38:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by EnvironmentTestController#index as JSON
2013-02-23T02:38:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"33"}
2013-02-23T02:38:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 14.0ms)
2013-02-23T02:38:19+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/environment_test/index.json?id=33 host=biotriz.herokuapp.com fwd="193.169.36.82" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=26ms status=200 bytes=266
```

In my manifest CSS file (**application.css**) two Kendo-related CSS-files are included: **kendo.common.min.css** (containing common code, [unminified version](http://paste.fedoraproject.org/3668/)) and **kendo.bootstrap.min.css** (theme-specific code, [unminified version](http://paste.fedoraproject.org/3667/)).

By the way, the `vendor` directory in `kendoui-rails` gem has the following structure:

```
vendor
└── assets
    ├── javascripts
    │   └── ...
    └── stylesheets
        └── kendo
            ├── Bootstrap
            │   ├── editor.png
            │   ├── imagebrowser.png
            │   ├── loading.gif
            │   ├── loading-image.gif
            │   ├── slider-h.gif
            │   ├── slider-v.gif
            │   └── sprite.png
            ├── ... # Some other theme-specific dirs
            ├── kendo.bootstrap.min.css
            ├── kendo.common.min.css
            └── ... # Some other theme-specific CSS's
```

The file **kendo.bootstrap.min.css** contains code referring to the images (`url('Bootstrap/sprite.png')` and `url('Bootstrap/loading.gif')`) which are not displayed in production (but they are present in the `Bootstrap` directory), so I think Chris Rueber was correct. So how can I fix that?

Comment: Please post your heroku logs so that we can troubleshoot the precompile error.

Comment: I agree with your assessment of it being an asset pipeline thing. How are the images (arrow/indicators) referred to in the CSS? On first glance, it sounds like something that the CSS might be referring to by a ../images/arrow-left.jpg kind of reference, which doesn't work right when it's inside the asset pipeline.

Comment: I have (almost) replicated your code on my machine and it seems if KendoUI is installed by the gem, there are no `css` files added , probably they are included as an engine. Please tell us how did you install Kendo UI.

Comment: @QumaraSixOneTour, my installation steps: 1) add the line `gem "kendoui-rails"` to the Gemfile; 2) run `rails generate kendoui:install --theme=bootstrap` after `bundle install`; (as the [blog post](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-03-01/building_rails_applications_with_the_kendoui-rails_gem.aspx) says). I didn't locate any Kendo UI CSS files inside the app's root as well, only in the gem installation directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `Bootstrap` folder to `vendor/assets/images` (or create it if it doesn't exist). Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is described in [the issues](https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-rails/issues/2) of [KendoUI-Rails github](https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-rails) repository. It seems to appear after precompiling the assets , due to merging the css files. This way the correct path to the `.png` file is lost. You can reproduce the bug in the production by setting the debug off , like this (in your `development.rb`):

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

The one possible workaround is to include the `.css` file separate from asset-pipeline, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/kendo/kendo.bootstrap.min.css">
```

but , as the author of the ticket [@fadzlan](https://github.com/fadzlan) explains, it would lead to `css` asset served by the `application server` instead of the `web server`.

Comment: Thanks. I actually should have checked the issue tracker myself.